# Pass selected value from <select> HTML markup to JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

How can i get the value of the `<select>` markup in my html and pass it on my javascript.

when i select `red` it should display my `<div id="red">` 
im new to JS, so im not sure if i got the correct syntax.

HTML

```
<select>
<option name="choice1" value="red" onclick="color(this.value)">red</option>
<option name="choice2" value="blue" onclick="color(this.value)">blue</option>
</select>

<div id="red" style="display:none;">
<p>You want RED</p>
</div>

<div id="blue" style="display:none;">
<p>You want BLUE</p>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function color(color_type){
if (color_type == 'blue'){
document.getElementById('blue').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'none';
} 
else{
document.getElementById('blue').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `onchange` event instead of `onclick`, besides, the event should set to select instead of option following is correct code

```
<script>
function color(color_type){
    if (color_type == 'blue'){
        document.getElementById('blue').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'none';
    } 
    else{
        document.getElementById('blue').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>

<select onchange="color(this.value)">
    <option name="choice1" value="red" >red</option>
    <option name="choice2" value="blue" >blue</option>
</select>

<div id="red" style="display:none;">
    <p>You want RED</p>
</div>

<div id="blue" style="display:none;">
    <p>You want BLUE</p>
</div>
```

Hope Helps!

Comment: thanks. also, in addition. whats the best approach if i have multiple `DIVS` to hide `document.getElementById('blue').style.display = 'block';` `document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'block';`
`document.getElementById('yellow').style.display = 'block';`
`document.getElementById('pink').style.display = 'block';`

Comment: @user1735120 I would suggest you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it's a very famous and widely used js library. To get multiple divs, you can assign the same class to all these divs, such as  <div id="red" class="colors"></div> <div id="blue" class="colors"></div>. In jQuery, if you want to hide all these divs,   it's really very easy: $('.colors').hide(); and if you want to show them: $('.colors').show()

Answer (score 1):

```
<select onchange="color(event)">
<option name="choice1" value="red" >red</option>
<option name="choice2" value="blue" >blue</option>
</select>


function color(e){

  var color=e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
  var blueDiv=document.getElementById('blue');
  var redDiv=document.getElementById('red');

  switch(color){
  case 'blue':
    blueDiv.style.display = 'block';
    redDiv.style.display = 'none';
    break;

  case 'red':
    redDiv.style.display = 'block';
    blueDiv.style.display = 'none';
    break;

  default:
    redDiv.style.display = 'none';
    blueDiv.style.display = 'none';
    break;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected value by using "value" method on "select" element object. For below html you can get the value of select tag by document.getElementById("color").value

```
<body>
  <select id="color">
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
  </select>

  <div id="red" style="display:none;">
    <p>You want RED</p>
  </div>

  <div id="blue" style="display:none;">
    <p>You want BLUE</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Heres how I have written my js :

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("change", function() {
      var selectElem = document.getElementById("color");
      document.getElementById("red").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("blue").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById(selectElem.value).style.display = "block";
    })
  })
</script>
```

Tip : Always try to implement DRY(Dont repeat your code) code.

The above code will not work in IE8 or below. IE8 and below browsers supports attachEvent() method. We can create our own custom event handler method that will work for cross browsers.

```
function addHandler(element, type, handler) {
  alert("Hi");
  if(element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
  } else if(element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent("on"+type, handler)
  } else { 
    element["on"+type] = handler };
}
addHandler(window, "load", main)

function main() {
  function handler() {
    var selectElem = document.getElementById("color");
    document.getElementById("red").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("blue").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(selectElem.value).style.display = "block";
  }
  addHandler(document.getElementById("color"), "change", handler);
}
```

I have created a custom addHandler() function that will work for all IE's, chrome, firefox, opera and safari.

Comment: i like this code. but i heard `.addEventListerner` doest like IE? is this true?

Comment: addEventListener is supported in IE9(or above), chrome, safari, firefox, opera. But for IE8 and below you can use attachEvent() which accepts two args same as first two args of addEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this

```
<select id="color" placeholder="{{__('Choose color')}}">
<option name="choice1" value="red" >red</option>
<option name="choice2" value="blue" >blue</option>
</select>

<div id="red" style="display:none;">
<p>You want RED</p>
</div>
<div id="blue" style="display:none;">
<p>You want BLUE</p>
</div>
```

This is the script

```
$('#color').change(

    function (){
        if($('#color').val()==='red'){
            $("#red").show();
            $("#blue").hide();
        }
        else{
           $("#blue").show();
           $("#red").hide();
        }

        }
);
```

You can check the selected value using `alert ($('#color').val());`

Answer (score -1):

Set the handler on your select instead of option:

```
<select ... onclick="color(this.value)" >...
```